# Merging Quickbooks (QBW) files with generated report

Tags: merge, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have a customer who accidently wrote about 3 megs of data to the wrong quickbooks file. They had a backup in the same folder for reasons unknown... however their accountant still was writing to the old file.  Now we have like a 3 meg difference between 2 250~ meg QB files and I need to figure out how to merge these files (which quickbooks does not support) and generate some sort of report so that they can get their accounting info semi straightened out in some sort of organised fasion.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for taking the time to read this.

(EDIT) - explanation for last few sentences above... They have conflicting invoice numbers and possibly other things due to last level of use of each file.

Answer (score 0):

Karl Irvin has a Data Transfer Utility that can be used to transfer transactions and list items between QBW files. www.q2.us - his tools are widely used and very reliable.

He also has a report combiner tool, if all you want to do is see reports that are taken from data in two files.

QQube (www.clearify.com) can also generate reports from multiple QBW files.